# MySQL Date Var changing after if condition

Tags: mysql, variables

```
SELECT DATEDEBUT, DATEFIN INTO DebutReserv2, FinReserv2 FROM RESERVATION WHERE IDCODEBARRES = v_codebarre ORDER BY DATEDEBUT LIMIT 0, 1;
        RETURN(Concat(DebutReserv2, ",", FinReserv2));
        If ((DebutReserv2 <= curdate()) and (FinReserv2 >= curdate())) THEN
            RETURN(Concat(DebutReserv2, ",", FinReserv2));
```

Having a bit of a problem here. In the first return, DebutReserv2 and FinReserv2 have a value assigned to them by the first select, but as soon as I pass the first if, the value of both variables change (And we are in the same loop). This code is also in a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Execution never reaches  the `IF` because of the first `RETURN` statement.